# Where do I get the ULONG LoginID values to pass to WTSConnectSession?

Tags: .net, c++, windows, windows-vista

Where do I get the ULONG LoginID values to pass to [WTSConnectSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394782(VS.85).aspx)? I need both a ULONG LogonId and a ULONG TargetLogonId.

Is this the same as the SessionID I'll get back from [WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(VS.85).aspx) when I pass in WTSSessionId? I suspect not (I tried it and WTSConnectSession did not work.)

The MSDN glossay says a logon identifier is a LUID which I can get via [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671(VS.85).aspx) but that is a structure, not a ULONG. Is there an API to get a ULONG loginId from an LUID?

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the same problem here. This answer is not marked as accepted...

Comment: too much time has passed and I am no longer working on this, so I don't know if the answer is the right one - no way for me to validate, sorry. if it works for others, please add a comment on the answer.

Comment: Except for the `WSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` function. I made a solution that works using the functions @Sunlight described. I don't have the code right now, as soon as I got it again (probably monday) I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the session ID from `WTSEnumerateSessions`, `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`, `ProcessIdToSessionId` and so on. The one from `WTSQuerySessionInformation` is also a session ID, of course.

Remember that you need two session IDs for this function.